# Can I connect an iPad and an Eye-Fi Card?

Tags: ipad, camera, ad-hoc

I have the Eye-Fi Pro X2 Card and an iPad. I just wonder if there is a way to transfer pictures from my camera wirelessly without going through the Internet or a real wireless network - basically I want an ad-hoc connection between the iPad and the card.

I do own the iPad camera connection kit which works, but that kinda defeats the purpose of an Eye-Fi Card in the first place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it's coming soon to Eye-Fi cards, and they will have firmware upgrades for all existing cards..

http://www.eye.fi/press-releases/great-images-and-instant-gratification-with-eye-fis-direct-mode-the-mobile-solution